# wix 3.5 Remember Company name during folder selection

Tags: c#, installation, wix, wix3.5

How do i get wix 3.5 to remember my company name as part of the user selected folder to be installed?

For example,

I usually install my files to C:\CompanyName and when the installer prompts user to select their preferred location to be installed, C:\CompanyName usualy replaced with [PATH TO USERS SELECTED FOLDER]. I would like it to add CompanyName to the end of the path.

[PATH TO USERS SELECTED FOLDER]\CompanyName

How can i achieve that?

Code below to install to C:\CompanyName

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <!-- Install stuff into [SystemDrive] folder. -->
    <!-- This is the folder where the website content will be located -->
    <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="CompanyName">
    </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extra directory to achieve your requirement

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <!-- Install stuff into [SystemDrive] folder. -->
      <!-- This is the folder where the website content will be located -->
      <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="[User selected path]">
        <Directory Id="CompanyName" Name="[Company Name]">
            <!-- Put all other directory here -->
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
```

Comment: Does not work! Probably i haven't clarify my problem. I want the CompanyName to be added on to the Userinterface when the user is selecting the path!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the path in the custom action or through WIX property.

In custom action check whether the INSTALLLOCATION contains your company name (using simple string function string.Contains). If it does not contains the company name then append the name to INSTALLLOCATION (`session["INSTALLLOCATION"] = session["INSTALLLOCATION"] + "Company Name"`)

Comment: I thought this should be the default behaviour. I installed a lot of programs and all of them always append company name at the end.

Comment: I don't think a custom action is needed to do this. There must be some settings that we missed!